# PYTHON - Creating a .json file

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, python-requests, tkinter-entry

Hello guys i m trying to save a .json file using entry from tkinter. The file is saving as i expected but seems to not be correct as a .json and its not formated. I m trying using the code below, is it correct?

```
def save(self):
        filename = self.profile_entry.get()
        if filename == "":
            msg = "Insert a profile name"
            messagebox.showinfo("Profile name is empty", msg)
            self.profile_entry.focus()
        else:
            line = str(["--name: "+self.name_entry.get(), "--telephone: "+self.telephone_entry.get(), "--address: "+self.address_entry.get()])
            profile = open('profile_'+filename+'.json', 'w')
            profile.write(line)
            profile.close()
```

If yes, how can i do the way back get self.name_entry.get(), self.telephone_entry.get, self.address_entry.get values without "--name: ", "--telephone: " and "--address: " using def load(self):?

Hope you help me!

Thank you guys!

Answer (score 0):

You can dump and load all kinds of Python objects (`dict`, `list`, ...) with the built-in `json` module. You can find the documentation at
https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html